# IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract! on Integer[]

Tags: java, sorting, exception

How the following can generate the error given in the title:

```
Integer[] length = whatever();
Arrays.sort(length);
```

All the questions I found about this exception have something to do with the comparison method. However, here the sorted objects are standard `Integer` instances.

I think this might have something to do with multi-threading, because the array returned by `whatever()` is something that can be recomputed by other threads.

Comment: If your other threads are accessing the array while its being sorted *anything* can happen. To just get a sorted array, you might want to just clone the array and sort the cloned copy. Although cloning while modifying it is still a bad idea... use proper thread communication to coordinate your threads.

Comment: I agree that I should work on the thread organization... but it'd take more time that I can't allocate to the concerned project. Next time I'll think about it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.Integer`'s `compareTo(Integer)` method does not violate any contract about sorting, of course. As you noted, though, `Arrays.sort` (and probably any other sorting algorithm implemented in the JDK) implicitly assumes that it's the only one manipulating the array. If this array is accessible from multiple threads, you'll have to protect the access to it, e.g., but using a `synchronized` block.

Comment: Should I syncronize the `length` array until end of use ?

Comment: `synchronize(length){ ... }` worked. 
But as @Durandal commented, I should properly design my application organisation with respect to data concurrency.

Comment: length is not a good choice for syncronization - it's an `int`, which will be autoboxed to an `Integer`. Depending on its value and the JDK implementation, it may or may not be **the same instance** of `Integer` - which means the synchronization may or may not be useless. I'd use the array itself to sync on.

Comment: `length` is the array (`Integer[] length`), or am I missing something?

Comment: @Juh_ no - I was missing something - I was thinking of `length.length` - my bad.

Comment: I guess, out of context, the name `length` was a poor choice :-/